# How to Change a Site Collection in WSS 3.0

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, master-page

I have a web application deployed in WSS 3.0, since I don't have the Office Publishing Feature how can I modify the masterpage of my site without affecting the site collection itself?

I'd be glad to add further details upon request since I haven't tried to do this yet.

Comment: Yes, please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are free 3th party solutions that let you change the master page. Search for "Master picker WSS 3.0"

Some sample solutions :
http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=SPMasterPicker

http://spfmasterpageselect.codeplex.com/releases/view/50100

Answer (score 1):

it all depends on what your trying to achive! what are you trying to do?

If I get you right you want to break the inheritance from the top level site so that it doesnt effect any other sub-sites?

Aslong as you dont change the toplevel masterpage that all the sites and subsites sit on then you can change as you please ;). If you change a subsite then it should only change any sites below it only! I dont think the parent can inherit the masterpage it only goes down not up!

So If your site is in a site collection you can change the masterpage and it will only effect that site and anything below it!

go to the homepage of the site you want to change and click on siteactions sitesettings then:

[image: add/change master page for that site]

Once you have done the above you can:

[image: Select masterpage and inheritance :)]

You can select the masterpage you want for that site and click on:

Apply to this site

or

Apply to this site and all its subsites

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes you got my question right. Unfortunately, I can't access the 'Select a Master Page' option under look and feel since it's not there (the feature is not installed). I may have to try the solution @W0ut suggested.

Comment: i dont know why someone downvoted this answer considering it is correct but you only require somthing slightly different as you dont have access to this part.